# Factory objects for Sails using sails-mongo adapter?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails framework with sails-mongo adapter as orm, I want to test models and controllers so I want a factory to provide model objects. When I use sql databases I use [factory-girl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/factory-girl) with sequelize as ORM, so I want an equivalent for mongo databases. I know there is an adapter for factory girl using mongoose, but nevertheless I read that is recommended to use sails-mongo (waterline) for sails framework instead of moongose.

Do you know a factory or how can I create objects(with associations) for this?

Thanks in advance.